Error on Moving from Sequential to LocalExecutor
I updated my airflow setup to use LocalExecutor but it started giving this error related to python's multiprocessing library:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: 'QueuedLocalWorker' object has no attribute 'wrapper'

It works fine with Sequential Executor but keeps queuing tasks with this error on the scheduler. (airflow version 2.10.3 and python 3.10). I am running airflow in python virtual environment.

having the same issue. downgraded to python 3.8 and also changed from MySql to PostGres, created new conda env, and cannot solve it. I am on local MacOS 14.

@KorayKinik you might find this discussion useful https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/44243#discussioncomment-11606856

In order to use the LocalExecutor, you need also need to upgrade your database by using MySql or Postgres. I recommend :

Using postgres : Create a db dedicate to airflow (like : airflow_db), create an user and grant him all control on this db

pip install psycopg2-binary and pip install apache-airflow[postgres]

Configure airflow.cfg (
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://:@:/airflow_db)

start db server

launch : airflow standalone



I already have a PostgreSQL database setup with airflow.

ok but have you made all the process i have describe above ?
